# F-distribution problem

Tags: statistics

I have a dataset. After I made my histogram it appears to be F-distribution. But I compute skewness and kurtosis and they are 15 and 45 values. Should I consider this as a fat-tailed distribution? How I can detect that this is not f-distribution, but maybe heavy tailed.

Comment: You might consider Kolmogorov--Smirnov (although I suspect there are more powerful tests when the null hypothesis considers such a narrow class of distributions). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There are many heavy tailed distributions in addition to F: exponential, gamma, lognormal, Weibull, etc. @MichaelHardy is correct that you _could_ use a K-S test to check for a _particular_ F (both df's known) if there are no (or few) ties. Anything is possible, I guess, but one rarely encounters raw data that are F-distributed. (Maybe in a simulation study, but then you'd likely know.) Some background about data source and objectives would be helpful in sorting this out. (Like what made you think your data might be F.)